# DataGridView column bind to string

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this definition in a WinForm:

```
private BindingList<String> rollbackLog = new BindingList<String>();
```

I have a DataGridView with a single column and I want to bind that column to this list.  The issue I have is I don't know what to assign to the DataPropertyName property of the column.  ie, I don't think there's a property of "string" which will return the value?

Do I have to define my own class with a string property and then read from that?

Using a ListBox would be the preferred option given I have only a single property, but this is more out of interest in the end.

Comment: As you only have one column, can't you use the ListView?

Comment: Yes, you are right too.  I think I started using the Datagrid because originally I did have multiple columns, but then returned it back to a single column but didn't look into changing my control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple wrapper class

```
class Foo
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and use

```
private BindingList<Foo> rollbackLog = new BindingList<Foo>();
```

and set `DataPropertyName` to `"SomeProperty"` .

Comment: Yep.  Thanks.  I was trying to inherit from String which obviously doesn't work.  Then got myself all confused.  I'll accept as soon as I'm allowed!

Comment: I was afraid of that answer.  <whine>Why did they have to make String sealed so we can't make the wrapper inherit?</whine>